# Solving a Cubic Function

Tags: functions, bezier-curve

Can someone help me find my solution(s) to this cubic equation?

```
x = a(1-t)^3 + 3bt(1-t)^2 + 3c(1-t)t^2 + dt^3
```

Where:

```
a = 1
b = 3
c = 8
d = 9
x = 5
```

Ultimately, I need to have the solutions with the variables in place so I can easily figure out how to substitute other constants in.

I've been working on this for weeks and I'm struggling! I've looked up cubic functions on wikipedia and I've gone back and reread both an algebra I and an algebra II books and I'm just not able to apply what I've found to this!

Basically, I need to be able to solve for `t` when I have `x` so I need an equation where `t = MyCalculatio`n. I understand that there could possibly be up to 3 solutions but in my circumstance there should never be more than 1 since my curve should never cross the same x or y plane more than once.

Comment: Wolfram answered [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281-t%29%5E3+%2B+9t%281-t%29%5E2+%2B+24%281-t%29t%5E2+%2B+9t%5E3+%3D+5&dataset=)

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful... I'm surprised I hadn't considered that yet. I was kind of hoping someone would help me figure out how to pull the each of the solutions out of my cubic equations though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a nice solution in terms of $a,b,c,d,$ and $x$, you're going to be disappointed. I used Maple to find solutions. For simplicity I'm only going to list the solutions that have no explicitly stated imaginary component.

If you restrict $a,b,c,$ and $d$ to be the values you gave, then

$t=1/14\,\sqrt [3]{916-196\,x+28\,\sqrt {77-458\,x+49\,{x}^{2}}}+{\frac {
46}{7}}\,{\frac {1}{\sqrt [3]{916-196\,x+28\,\sqrt {77-458\,x+49\,{x}^
{2}}}}}+3/7$

Otherwise, you get this hideously messy solution (sorry if the formatting is horrible. There's really no way around that.)

$1/2\,{\frac {\sqrt [3]{24\,cdx+24\,a{c}^{2}-36\,x{c}^{2}+4\,\sqrt {6\,
{x}^{2}bd+4\,a{c}^{3}-3\,{b}^{2}{c}^{2}+9\,{x}^{2}{c}^{2}-6\,acbd+6\,a
xcb-18\,{x}^{2}bc+6\,a{x}^{2}c-12\,ax{c}^{2}-2\,{a}^{2}xd+{a}^{2}{d}^{
2}+4\,{b}^{3}d+{x}^{2}{d}^{2}-4\,{b}^{3}x-4\,{c}^{3}x+{a}^{2}{x}^{2}+6
\,cbdx+6\,acdx+6\,abdx-12\,{b}^{2}dx+6\,xc{b}^{2}+6\,xb{c}^{2}-2\,a{x}
^{2}d-2\,ax{d}^{2}-6\,cd{x}^{2}+9\,{x}^{2}{b}^{2}-6\,a{x}^{2}b}a-12\,
\sqrt {6\,{x}^{2}bd+4\,a{c}^{3}-3\,{b}^{2}{c}^{2}+9\,{x}^{2}{c}^{2}-6
\,acbd+6\,axcb-18\,{x}^{2}bc+6\,a{x}^{2}c-12\,ax{c}^{2}-2\,{a}^{2}xd+{
a}^{2}{d}^{2}+4\,{b}^{3}d+{x}^{2}{d}^{2}-4\,{b}^{3}x-4\,{c}^{3}x+{a}^{
2}{x}^{2}+6\,cbdx+6\,acdx+6\,abdx-12\,{b}^{2}dx+6\,xc{b}^{2}+6\,xb{c}^
{2}-2\,a{x}^{2}d-2\,ax{d}^{2}-6\,cd{x}^{2}+9\,{x}^{2}{b}^{2}-6\,a{x}^{
2}b}b+12\,\sqrt {6\,{x}^{2}bd+4\,a{c}^{3}-3\,{b}^{2}{c}^{2}+9\,{x}^{2}
{c}^{2}-6\,acbd+6\,axcb-18\,{x}^{2}bc+6\,a{x}^{2}c-12\,ax{c}^{2}-2\,{a
}^{2}xd+{a}^{2}{d}^{2}+4\,{b}^{3}d+{x}^{2}{d}^{2}-4\,{b}^{3}x-4\,{c}^{
3}x+{a}^{2}{x}^{2}+6\,cbdx+6\,acdx+6\,abdx-12\,{b}^{2}dx+6\,xc{b}^{2}+
6\,xb{c}^{2}-2\,a{x}^{2}d-2\,ax{d}^{2}-6\,cd{x}^{2}+9\,{x}^{2}{b}^{2}-
6\,a{x}^{2}b}c-4\,\sqrt {6\,{x}^{2}bd+4\,a{c}^{3}-3\,{b}^{2}{c}^{2}+9
\,{x}^{2}{c}^{2}-6\,acbd+6\,axcb-18\,{x}^{2}bc+6\,a{x}^{2}c-12\,ax{c}^
{2}-2\,{a}^{2}xd+{a}^{2}{d}^{2}+4\,{b}^{3}d+{x}^{2}{d}^{2}-4\,{b}^{3}x
-4\,{c}^{3}x+{a}^{2}{x}^{2}+6\,cbdx+6\,acdx+6\,abdx-12\,{b}^{2}dx+6\,x
c{b}^{2}+6\,xb{c}^{2}-2\,a{x}^{2}d-2\,ax{d}^{2}-6\,cd{x}^{2}+9\,{x}^{2
}{b}^{2}-6\,a{x}^{2}b}d+24\,xab-24\,xbd-12\,bad-12\,cad-12\,cbd+8\,xad
+8\,{b}^{3}+8\,{c}^{3}+4\,{a}^{2}d+24\,{b}^{2}d-4\,x{a}^{2}-4\,x{d}^{2
}+4\,a{d}^{2}-12\,c{b}^{2}-12\,b{c}^{2}-12\,abc-24\,xac+72\,xcb-36\,x{
b}^{2}}}{a-3\,b+3\,c-d}}-2\,{\frac {ac-ad-{b}^{2}+cb+bd-{c}^{2}}{
 \left( a-3\,b+3\,c-d \right) \sqrt [3]{24\,cdx+24\,a{c}^{2}-36\,x{c}^
{2}+4\,\sqrt {6\,{x}^{2}bd+4\,a{c}^{3}-3\,{b}^{2}{c}^{2}+9\,{x}^{2}{c}
^{2}-6\,acbd+6\,axcb-18\,{x}^{2}bc+6\,a{x}^{2}c-12\,ax{c}^{2}-2\,{a}^{
2}xd+{a}^{2}{d}^{2}+4\,{b}^{3}d+{x}^{2}{d}^{2}-4\,{b}^{3}x-4\,{c}^{3}x
+{a}^{2}{x}^{2}+6\,cbdx+6\,acdx+6\,abdx-12\,{b}^{2}dx+6\,xc{b}^{2}+6\,
xb{c}^{2}-2\,a{x}^{2}d-2\,ax{d}^{2}-6\,cd{x}^{2}+9\,{x}^{2}{b}^{2}-6\,
a{x}^{2}b}a-12\,\sqrt {6\,{x}^{2}bd+4\,a{c}^{3}-3\,{b}^{2}{c}^{2}+9\,{
x}^{2}{c}^{2}-6\,acbd+6\,axcb-18\,{x}^{2}bc+6\,a{x}^{2}c-12\,ax{c}^{2}
-2\,{a}^{2}xd+{a}^{2}{d}^{2}+4\,{b}^{3}d+{x}^{2}{d}^{2}-4\,{b}^{3}x-4
\,{c}^{3}x+{a}^{2}{x}^{2}+6\,cbdx+6\,acdx+6\,abdx-12\,{b}^{2}dx+6\,xc{
b}^{2}+6\,xb{c}^{2}-2\,a{x}^{2}d-2\,ax{d}^{2}-6\,cd{x}^{2}+9\,{x}^{2}{
b}^{2}-6\,a{x}^{2}b}b+12\,\sqrt {6\,{x}^{2}bd+4\,a{c}^{3}-3\,{b}^{2}{c
}^{2}+9\,{x}^{2}{c}^{2}-6\,acbd+6\,axcb-18\,{x}^{2}bc+6\,a{x}^{2}c-12
\,ax{c}^{2}-2\,{a}^{2}xd+{a}^{2}{d}^{2}+4\,{b}^{3}d+{x}^{2}{d}^{2}-4\,
{b}^{3}x-4\,{c}^{3}x+{a}^{2}{x}^{2}+6\,cbdx+6\,acdx+6\,abdx-12\,{b}^{2
}dx+6\,xc{b}^{2}+6\,xb{c}^{2}-2\,a{x}^{2}d-2\,ax{d}^{2}-6\,cd{x}^{2}+9
\,{x}^{2}{b}^{2}-6\,a{x}^{2}b}c-4\,\sqrt {6\,{x}^{2}bd+4\,a{c}^{3}-3\,
{b}^{2}{c}^{2}+9\,{x}^{2}{c}^{2}-6\,acbd+6\,axcb-18\,{x}^{2}bc+6\,a{x}
^{2}c-12\,ax{c}^{2}-2\,{a}^{2}xd+{a}^{2}{d}^{2}+4\,{b}^{3}d+{x}^{2}{d}
^{2}-4\,{b}^{3}x-4\,{c}^{3}x+{a}^{2}{x}^{2}+6\,cbdx+6\,acdx+6\,abdx-12
\,{b}^{2}dx+6\,xc{b}^{2}+6\,xb{c}^{2}-2\,a{x}^{2}d-2\,ax{d}^{2}-6\,cd{
x}^{2}+9\,{x}^{2}{b}^{2}-6\,a{x}^{2}b}d+24\,xab-24\,xbd-12\,bad-12\,ca
d-12\,cbd+8\,xad+8\,{b}^{3}+8\,{c}^{3}+4\,{a}^{2}d+24\,{b}^{2}d-4\,x{a
}^{2}-4\,x{d}^{2}+4\,a{d}^{2}-12\,c{b}^{2}-12\,b{c}^{2}-12\,abc-24\,xa
c+72\,xcb-36\,x{b}^{2}}}}+{\frac {a-2\,b+c}{a-3\,b+3\,c-d}}
$

If you're ok with an approximate solution, then I suggest you try some computational methods rather than using the exact solution.

Comment: you're awesome! Unfortunately, thats exactly what I needed! You're right that the formatting is messed up. My formatting questions: how does 1/2 at the beginning and the -2 in the middle fall into place and there seems to be an odd break in the middle of the square roots.

Comment: What is Maple? Approximate solutions should work though... Can you point me in a direction for computational methods?

Comment: If you right-click on the math you should have the option to see it as TeX commands. Copy that and view it using your favourite typesetting program (I recommend TeXShop). That should give you some control over the formatting. Maple is a fantastic piece of software that can do all sorts of math related tasks. As for computational methods, it shouldn't be too hard for you to implement a simple root-finding algorithm (provided you know how to write code). Maybe try Newton's method?